# django and mod_wsgi: TemplateSyntaxError - list index out of range

Tags: django, mod-wsgi

Yikes. Trying to run my Django app on Apache using mod_wsgi. Running into so many error. Here's the latest one that I cannot figure out:

```
   [Fri Apr 22 23:21:31 2011] [error] [client ::1] mod_wsgi (pid=23999): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/Users/kevin/PycharmProjects/ml/apache/django.wsgi'.
[Fri Apr 22 23:21:31 2011] [error] [client ::1] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Fri Apr 22 23:21:31 2011] [error] [client ::1]   File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 273, in __call__
[Fri Apr 22 23:21:31 2011] [error] [client ::1]     response = self.get_response(request)
[Fri Apr 22 23:21:31 2011] [error] [client ::1]   File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 169, in get_response
[Fri Apr 22 23:21:31 2011] [error] [client ::1]     response = self.handle_uncaught_exception(request, resolver, sys.exc_info())
[Fri Apr 22 23:21:31 2011] [error] [client ::1]   File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 203, in handle_uncaught_exception
[Fri Apr 22 23:21:31 2011] [error] [client ::1]     return debug.technical_500_response(request, *exc_info)
[Fri Apr 22 23:21:31 2011] [error] [client ::1]   File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/views/debug.py", line 59, in technical_500_response
[Fri Apr 22 23:21:31 2011] [error] [client ::1]     html = reporter.get_traceback_html()
[Fri Apr 22 23:21:31 2011] [error] [client ::1]   File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/views/debug.py", line 151, in get_traceback_html
[Fri Apr 22 23:21:31 2011] [error] [client ::1]     return t.render(c)
[Fri Apr 22 23:21:31 2011] [error] [client ::1]   File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 123, in render
[Fri Apr 22 23:21:31 2011] [error] [client ::1]     return self._render(context)
[Fri Apr 22 23:21:31 2011] [error] [client ::1]   File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 117, in _render
[Fri Apr 22 23:21:31 2011] [error] [client ::1]     return self.nodelist.render(context)
[Fri Apr 22 23:21:31 2011] [error] [client ::1]   File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 744, in render
[Fri Apr 22 23:21:31 2011] [error] [client ::1]     bits.append(self.render_node(node, context))
[Fri Apr 22 23:21:31 2011] [error] [client ::1]   File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/template/debug.py", line 73, in render_node
[Fri Apr 22 23:21:31 2011] [error] [client ::1]     result = node.render(context)
[Fri Apr 22 23:21:31 2011] [error] [client ::1]   File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/template/debug.py", line 90, in render
[Fri Apr 22 23:21:31 2011] [error] [client ::1]     output = self.filter_expression.resolve(context)
[Fri Apr 22 23:21:31 2011] [error] [client ::1]   File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 536, in resolve
[Fri Apr 22 23:21:31 2011] [error] [client ::1]     new_obj = func(obj, *arg_vals)
[Fri Apr 22 23:21:31 2011] [error] [client ::1]   File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/template/defaultfilters.py", line 695, in date
[Fri Apr 22 23:21:31 2011] [error] [client ::1]     return format(value, arg)
[Fri Apr 22 23:21:31 2011] [error] [client ::1]   File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/utils/dateformat.py", line 285, in format
[Fri Apr 22 23:21:31 2011] [error] [client ::1]     return df.format(format_string)
[Fri Apr 22 23:21:31 2011] [error] [client ::1]   File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/utils/dateformat.py", line 30, in format
[Fri Apr 22 23:21:31 2011] [error] [client ::1]     pieces.append(force_unicode(getattr(self, piece)()))
[Fri Apr 22 23:21:31 2011] [error] [client ::1]   File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/utils/dateformat.py", line 191, in r
[Fri Apr 22 23:21:31 2011] [error] [client ::1]     return self.format('D, j M Y H:i:s O')
[Fri Apr 22 23:21:31 2011] [error] [client ::1]   File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/utils/dateformat.py", line 30, in format
[Fri Apr 22 23:21:31 2011] [error] [client ::1]     pieces.append(force_unicode(getattr(self, piece)()))
[Fri Apr 22 23:21:31 2011] [error] [client ::1]   File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/utils/encoding.py", line 71, in force_unicode
[Fri Apr 22 23:21:31 2011] [error] [client ::1]     s = unicode(s)
[Fri Apr 22 23:21:31 2011] [error] [client ::1]   File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 206, in __unicode_cast
[Fri Apr 22 23:21:31 2011] [error] [client ::1]     return self.__func(*self.__args, **self.__kw)
[Fri Apr 22 23:21:31 2011] [error] [client ::1]   File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/utils/translation/__init__.py", line 81, in ugettext
[Fri Apr 22 23:21:31 2011] [error] [client ::1]     return _trans.ugettext(message)
[Fri Apr 22 23:21:31 2011] [error] [client ::1]   File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 286, in ugettext
[Fri Apr 22 23:21:31 2011] [error] [client ::1]     return do_translate(message, 'ugettext')
[Fri Apr 22 23:21:31 2011] [error] [client ::1]   File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 276, in do_translate
[Fri Apr 22 23:21:31 2011] [error] [client ::1]     _default = translation(settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)
[Fri Apr 22 23:21:31 2011] [error] [client ::1]   File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 185, in translation
[Fri Apr 22 23:21:31 2011] [error] [client ::1]     default_translation = _fetch(settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)
[Fri Apr 22 23:21:31 2011] [error] [client ::1]   File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 162, in _fetch
[Fri Apr 22 23:21:31 2011] [error] [client ::1]     app = import_module(appname)
[Fri Apr 22 23:21:31 2011] [error] [client ::1]   File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
[Fri Apr 22 23:21:31 2011] [error] [client ::1]     __import__(name)
[Fri Apr 22 23:21:31 2011] [error] [client ::1]   File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/haystack/__init__.py", line 154, in <module>
[Fri Apr 22 23:21:31 2011] [error] [client ::1]     handle_registrations()
[Fri Apr 22 23:21:31 2011] [error] [client ::1]   File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/haystack/__init__.py", line 151, in handle_registrations
[Fri Apr 22 23:21:31 2011] [error] [client ::1]     search_sites_conf = importlib.import_module(settings.HAYSTACK_SITECONF)
[Fri Apr 22 23:21:31 2011] [error] [client ::1]   File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
[Fri Apr 22 23:21:31 2011] [error] [client ::1]     __import__(name)
[Fri Apr 22 23:21:31 2011] [error] [client ::1]   File "/Users/kevin/PycharmProjects/mg/../mg/search_sites.py", line 1, in <module>
[Fri Apr 22 23:21:31 2011] [error] [client ::1]     import haystack
[Fri Apr 22 23:21:31 2011] [error] [client ::1]   File "/Users/kevin/PycharmProjects/mg/haystack/__init__.py", line 154, in <module>
[Fri Apr 22 23:21:31 2011] [error] [client ::1]   File "/Users/kevin/PycharmProjects/mg/haystack/__init__.py", line 143, in handle_registrations
[Fri Apr 22 23:21:31 2011] [error] [client ::1]   File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/inspect.py", line 955, in stack
[Fri Apr 22 23:21:31 2011] [error] [client ::1]     return getouterframes(sys._getframe(1), context)
[Fri Apr 22 23:21:31 2011] [error] [client ::1]   File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/inspect.py", line 936, in getouterframes
[Fri Apr 22 23:21:31 2011] [error] [client ::1]     framelist.append((frame,) + getframeinfo(frame, context))
[Fri Apr 22 23:21:31 2011] [error] [client ::1]   File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/inspect.py", line 911, in getframeinfo
[Fri Apr 22 23:21:31 2011] [error] [client ::1]     lines, lnum = findsource(frame)
[Fri Apr 22 23:21:31 2011] [error] [client ::1]   File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/inspect.py", line 573, in findsource
[Fri Apr 22 23:21:31 2011] [error] [client ::1]     if pat.match(lines[lnum]): break
[Fri Apr 22 23:21:31 2011] [error] [client ::1] TemplateSyntaxError: Caught IndexError while rendering: list index out of range
```

One thing that's weird is I don't know why `PycharmProjects/mg` is even mentioned. My project used to live under the folder 'mg' but I've changed it to 'ml' quite some time ago. I have no trouble in dev server of course. I read on another SO thread about changing mod_wsgi to Daemon as a solution, but that did not work for me.

Thank you.

Comment: OK I ended up deleting the Haystack source code from my Django app directory, and now it's working fine. I guess I should bring this up with Haystack.

Answer (score 0):

I think wrong wsgi file is the reason. Check your apache site file.

```
WSGIScriptAlias /path/to/your/wsgi
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I don't think that's the problem. `/Users/kevin/PycharmProjects/ml/apache/django.wsgi` is the correct path, as written in the first line of the errors I pasted.